# How i convert decimal number with point to binary number in c#?

Tags: c#

```
In this web i see that all answer about thins like converting decimal number to     binary
its refers number without point in the number(int)...
i want to know how to convert the decimal number with point like "332.434" to binary in c#
```

exemple i see:

```
using System;

namespace _01.Decimal_to_Binary
{
    class DecimalToBinary
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Decimal: ");
            int decimalNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int remainder;
            string result = string.Empty;
            while (decimalNumber > 0)
            {
                remainder = decimalNumber % 2;
                decimalNumber /= 2;
                result = remainder.ToString() + result;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Binary:  {0}",result);
        }
    }
}
```

the exemple refer to convert from int without point

thank

Answer (score 1):

Just use a BitConverter to get the bytes then loop over them converting those to strings and appending the current string of bits to the previous one.

```
byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(MyDouble);
string ByteString = System.String.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
    ByteString = Convert.ToString(byteArray[i], 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
```

You may have to do some tinkering to get the bits in the correct order but I assume BysteString will have the high order bits on the left. Here's the MSDN page for that ToString method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s62fh68.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You can't simply convert non integer number to a binary format. E.g. for 3.145926 a computer keeps a sign (+/-), a number itself but with a lead zero alway (0.3141596) and a mantissa (E-1). So you need to keep all 3 parts. Read more in wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding

Comment: This is a simple task. The complexity of how a float is represented in binary has no impact on the difficulty of converting it to a bit string. The process is no different than it is for any other primitive type. Get the bytes, then convert those to bit strings.